# Отсчет времени

Tags: таймер, c#

Я бы хотел задать вопрос. Мне нужно, чтобы на форме при включении отображался процесс отсчета времени после, например, 30 секунд кнопка стала доступной.

Comment: Для отсчёта времени есть многочисленные таймеры, в том числе и в графических фреймворках. Для остального ответ зависит от используемого фреймворка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Thread ch;//создаем публичную переменную для потока
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Enabled = false;//делаем кнопку не аткивной
            ch = new Thread(chan);//создаем сам поток
            ch.Start(ch);//запускаем поток
        }
        public void chan(object obj)//фунция потока
        {
            int i = 30;//задаем счетчик
            while (i != -1)//цикл
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = i.ToString()));//выводим сколько времени осталось
                i--; //минусум счетчик
                ((Thread)obj).Join(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));//приостановливаем поток на одну секудну
            }
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => button1.Enabled = true));//активируем кнопку
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня ошибки какието вылазиют можно по подробнее 
Timer tim = new Timer();//создаем таймер
tim.Interval = 3000;//задаем время
tim.Tick += tim_Tick;//подписываем на события
tim.Start();//запускаем таймер
//делаем отсчет времени на форме
while (проверяем работает ли таймер)
{
label2;//тут выводим сколько времени осталось
}
void tim_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
droneButton3//Делаем кнопку активной 
} вот так

Comment: @cas-live: Это же холостой цикл, вы представляете, как он будет грузить процессор? Не говоря уже о зависшем UI.

Comment: Все равно не пойму.
___________
Расскажи так, чтобы прям тупой понял.

Comment: @cas-live: на WPF:

    var remainingTicks = 30;
    var t = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
    t.Tick += (s, args) =>
        {
            uiLabel.Text = remainingTicks.ToString();
            remainingTicks--;
            if (remainingTicks <= 0)
                t.Stop();
        };
    t.Start();

Без зависаний, без холостого цикла, без дополнительного потока.

Comment: @cas-live: Сделать паузу в секунду можно и проще:

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

Comment: @VladD, конечно можно,но вдруг пользователю нужно будет указать минуты или часы,то легче это сделать так

Comment: @cas-live: Тогда [`Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromDays(3))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/274eh01d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @VladD, Это практически не отличается от моего варианта, но давайте прекратим этот бессмысленный спор. С новым годом!

Comment: @cas-live: С новым годом!